# lodash tree shaking failed with typescript in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash, tree-shaking

i have some of big project using typescript.

I've tried several ways to tree shake lodash.

I think it's better to see the output of my work first.

my build command is

**build command**

```
ng build --stats-json
webpack-bundle-analyzer {{stats.json path}}
```

**custom_loadsh.ts**

```
export { forEach } from 'lodash/forEach';
export { cloneDeep } from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
...
..
.
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import * as _ from './custom_lodash';
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   ...
   ngOnInit() {
       let data = {
          test: 1  
       };
       let data2 = _.cloneDeep(data);
   }
   ...
}
```

Instead of getting the whole of lodash through custom_lodash, only some of them are imported.

[image]

Of course, the example code above is a bit different from the actual project, but the overall configuration is the same.

I wonder why lodash tree shaking fails.

This is the site I referenced.
https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/tree-shake-lodash-with-webpack-jest-and-typescript-2734fa13b5cd

Comment: Isn't that the expected behaviour?

Comment: @Vega sorry my mistake i already edit that

Comment: @Vega nope. I put up the site I referenced.As that column says, lodash.js is gone and there should be only a few files imported.

Comment: Why would you even need to use Lodash for `forEach` and `cloneDeep` functions when you already have native support for that with `forEach` and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`?

Comment: ouch.... sure you are right if i use only that function. that was sample code. my actually code use lodash function over 10. some of that function didnt support js native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was problem.

the problem is another package in node_modules.

in my case, `ngx-treeview` package use lodash.

this is sample code in `ngx-treeview`

```
import { isNil, isString } from 'lodash';
```

so, i`ll try below.

```
import isNil from 'lodash/isString';
import isString from 'lodash/isNil';
```

but.. this solution is temporary.

i'll try report issue to `ngx-treeview` github. unfortunately, last edit that package over 1 year.

so, i just fork that branch.